# Python FastAPI building a single-threaded queue of jobs after API call

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery, fastapi, distributed-system

I am trying to build an API for Selenium-based web scraper. The issue is, that for the web scraper to work it should always have the window active.

So if I create an API async endpoint which will start web-scraping for one page and then call API for another page, the former one will stop being an active window.

The first idea was to introduce locks for the API endpoint, which is a bad solution, as it is not logical that you cannot call API while another job is being done (3-4 minutes).

So my idea is to create a queue of jobs. When API endpoint is called, it adds a job to the queue. Then consumer on the server-side takes job, scrapes all the data and returns the result to the caller.

My background is that I am a student with some theory base but without too much practice. So I would like to know, what are the best practices to implement such producer-consumer solution in Python?

Comment: I've looked into it and it seems to me that it will return a "OK" message after sent the request and will just continue to do the task in the background. But the issue is, that when another request comes at the same time, it will start a second process with a second scraper, that's what I want to avoid. 
Also, on this page they say about Celery and RabbitMQ, could that be the implementation I need to use? But I think Celery is used when you have many workers, but I have just one.

Comment: You can absolutely use Celery with just one worker, and that would be my recommendation. To do what you're describing (strictly one task at a time), I think you want to start your worker with `--pool=solo`, but you'll have to read the docs and experiment a bit for that.